# how to get id of current object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

how to get current id instead of static id (7)
to add image to flat

'''

```
class CreateFlat(CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = CreateFlat
queryset = Flat.objects.all()
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.data)
    my_img = request.data['id_image']
    ima = Images.objects.get(id=my_img)
    print(self.id)
    print(self)
    flat = Flat.objects.get(id=7)
    flat.images.add(ima);
    serializer = FlatSerializer(flat, many=True)
    return Response("done")
```

'''

Comment: `self.id` didn't do it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'CreateFlat' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: How do you identify which `Flat` object should be chosen? How are you passing the flat id?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many errors but I think I can make you clear

First of all I would like to tell you about your view in general:

- If you use `CreateAPIView` it using `CreateModelMixin` you should work with `create` method, not post, but it does not really matter ok.
- In `CreateAPIView` there is only post method so you can remove `queryset` attribute
- Keep your view class thin and add your logic in serializer, `create` method in serializer in this case

And finally about your question. if your path url looks like this `flat/<int:pk>/add-images` then try this

```
lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
id = self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]
```